# Excel: Count Only Once If Another Column Has Duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, countif

I am trying to create a formula that will count the number of "Overdue" people instead of "Overdue" cells. Each person has the multiple rows with their name in it. The criteria to determine if it's "overdue" is:

-Column F and G are not within 3 years

-Column G are blank

-Column F = 0 and Column G are not within 3 years

The following code counts the criteria accurately. And doesn't account for duplicate names.

`=SUM(COUNTIFS(TT[Fiscal Law 301 CBT],"<"&TODAY()-1065,TT[Fiscal Law 301 CBT],">"&TODAY()-1095,TT[Fiscal Law In-Residence],"<"&TODAY()-1065,TT[Fiscal Law In-Residence],">"&TODAY()-1095),COUNTIFS(TT[Fiscal Law In-Residence],"",TT[Fiscal Law 301 CBT],"<"&TODAY()-1065,TT[Fiscal Law 301 CBT],">"&TODAY()-1095))`

The formula I want should count based on the criteria above and check `column Z` `TT[Name]` for duplicates and count them only once. And also count unique values once.

[image]

I just thought of another approach to this problem. What if I use the formula I have to create an Array, have another formula count the number of duplicates in `Column Z` from that Array, and subtract the two numbers.

This way should get me the correct number, i will still need assistance creating the second formula.

Comment: It would be helpful to know how your data is setup. Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57616566/edit) to provide a sample?

Comment: This is pretty confusing without a screenshot of your workbook. If you could share that, It'd help us answer faster!

Comment: My apologies, i meant to add one before i posted.

Comment: What you are after is a distinct count. Excel has a function for that in the new Dynamic Array function set, which is in Office 365 Insider builds but not avalable to everyone.

Comment: Or at least provide a screenshot where we can see Column and Row names? Thx

Comment: please clarify what do you mean by **Overdue**? What is the judging criteria?

Comment: I have updated the entire question. Hopefully it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is a distinct count. Excel has a function for that in the new Dynamic Array function set, which is in Office 365 Insider builds but not available to everyone. Right now, a distinct count requires a few tricks.

For example, you can create a pivot table with the names in the rows, filter the table to include only values where column X = Overdue and use a CountA() on the result rows.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but not quite there.

Use a countifs formula like above. Then, create a column next to it with the logic if(countcell>0, 1, 0). This will return 1 if the person has at least 1 book overdue, and 0 otherwise. Then, take the sum of that column.

[Formulas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnaYs.png)[image: Formulas]

[image: result]

I have provided a screenshots of the code that we would use (the E and F columns are dates). As you can see, the G column counts how many books are overdue. The H column provides a 1 if at least 1 book is overdue for each user. Then, we can simply sum the H column to find the total number of users with overdue books.

If this helps you, please consider choosing this as the answer.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? i'm not following exactly what your saying.

Comment: I think we are getting closer, using your scenario. Lets say for every overdue book there is a line created even if the user already has a line. So Al would have 2 lines. How do i count his name only once? Showing How many people have overdue books instead of total overdue books?

Comment: I added another thought on how to get there under the picture in my question.